Почему sem_t представлен именно в виде union?
Изучая синхронизацию, обнаружил, что sem_t в заголовочном файле bits/semaphore.h представлен в виде union:
typedef union
{
  char __size[__SIZEOF_SEM_T];
  long int __align;
} sem_t;

Для чего же был выбран именно union, а не например struct? Какие у него есть преимущества в данном случае?
Благодарю заранее за ответ

Похоже, просто для выравнивания...

А зачем оно нужно в данной ситуации? Почему бы тогда не использовать struct?
Я плохо в этом понимаю, поэтому извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос.

Ну, может, для эффективности? :) А struct требовало бы куда больших телодвижений, как мне кажется. Впрочем, пусть об этом расскажут специалисты в выравнивании, я к таким себя не отношу.

Структуру нужно оборачивать в специальный атрибут для компилятора, скорее всего просто непереносимо между версиями компилятора и-или компиляторами.
